# Uninstall MySQL 8.0 and Install 5.7

Tags: linux, installation, mysql, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I am trying to downgrade `mysql` version from 8.0 to 5.7. I was able to successfully uninstall MySQL 8.0, but when i try to install 5.7 I am getting following error.

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.27-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.27-1.el7
           Installed: mysql-community-common-8.0.17-1.el7.x86_64 (@mysql80-community)
               mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 8.0.17-1.el7
```

I have executed following commands:

1) Add MySQL Repository:

`rpm -ivh https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm`

2) Install MySQL 5.7:

`yum -y install mysql-community-server  --disablerepo=mysql80-community --enablerepo=mysql57-community`

Any help in this regard would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is quite clear. **mysql-community-server** requires **mysql-community-common** package with the exact same version number. So you also need to uninstall **mysql-community-common-8.0.17-1.el7.x86_64**

```
rpm -e mysql-community-common-8.0.17-1.el7.x86_64
```

or

```
zypper remove mysql-community-common-8.0.17-1.el7.x86_64
```

such that you can install the 5.7 version.

Comment: it worked! thank you!

Comment: An upvote says 'thank you'. Consider also accepting the answer if your problem is solved.